Adding logicapp as api permission to application object
I want to add my logicapp to an application object using the api permission tab. Im not getting my logicapp up in the list, why is that how can i fix it.

Can you share the steps of what you have tried so far? @Beefybanana

@IkhtesamAfrin i tried using access control(IAM) to allow the application object to use the Logicapp using systemassigned identity but i still cant see it.

You can assign in this way. You need to use User, group, or service principal @Beefybanana

To grant access to a registered app in logic app, you need to navigate to Access control (IAM) then click on Add role assignment.
I am granting Logic app contributor role, you can select the role as per your requirement.
You need to select User, group or service principal to assign RBAC role to an app.

If you are assigning permission to logic app's managed identity in any other app like function app, then in that case you need to choose Managed Identity.
